# How to implement custom html into body with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I need to implement

```
<img src="url" width="1" height="1" style="display:none" />
```

into  at the beginning of it with the help of Google Tag Manager (and you guys).

How to do this?

Comment: I was trying to say: implement img src tag into body

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does only allow to append to the end of the body - so instead of appending to the body, you have to insert before the first child of the body.

Create a custom HTML tag, and insert

```
<script>
// create the image
    var img = document.createElement("img");
// set properties such as a weird example url and style
    img.src = "https://www.kukksi.de/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/19-Disney-13-Goofy-und-Max.jpg";
    img.style = "display:none";
// insert before the first child element of the body, which will place the element at the beginning of the body
    document.body.insertBefore(img, document.body.firstChild);
</script>
```

I have to say that is is very hard to imagine a valid use case, though.